# To check if function attains maximum at given critical point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> For what real values of $x$ and $y$, does the integral $\int_x^y\left(6-t-t^2\right)\;dt$ attain its maximum?
>
> (A) $x=-3,y=2$
> (B) $x=2,y=3$
> (C) $x=-2,y=2$
> (D) $x=-3,y=4$

I have integrated it and after putting limits I have got my function of two variables. After doing routine method I have found answer to be A, but I am unsure of my method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental theorem makes this easy. The derivative is $6-t-t^2$. y needs to be a maximum and x needs to be a minimum. Solving $0=6-t-t^2$ we find that t must equal 2 or -3. At 0 the function is increasing, at infinity the function is decreasing, and at negative infinity the function is decreasing. So $t=2$ is a maximum and $t=-3$ is an inflection point. This eliminates (b) and (d). The function's inflection point is at -3, but on (-3,2) the function is increasing, so this implies F(-3) will be less than F(-2), because inflection points are just halts to an eventual unbounded increase or in this case decrease. (A) is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$F(x,y)= \int_x^y{6-t-t^2}dt = 6t - \dfrac{t^2}{2}-\dfrac{t^3}{3} |_{x}^y$$

Let's first check

$$g(t) = \int_0^{t}{6-t-t^2} dt=6t - \dfrac{t^2}{2}-\dfrac{t^3}{3}  $$

where it is maxima (or minima)?

$$\dfrac{dg}{dt} =  0 \implies 6-t-t^2=0 \implies t_1=-3 \land t_2=2$$

$$\dfrac{d^2g}{dt^2} |_{t_i} = -1-2t_i \implies \dfrac{d^2g}{dt^2} |_{t_1} = 5 \land \dfrac{d^2g}{dt^2} |_{t_2} = -5 $$

so $t=-3$ is the minima and $t=2$ is the maxima. We also have

$$ F(x,y) = g(y)-g(x)$$

It's easy to prove that the maximum value of $F(x,y)$ comes when $y$ is the maximum of $g(t)$ and $x$ is the minimum of the same.

Comment: is A correct ? .

Comment: Yes, it is correct